Bluespec Verilog - polymorphic vector type
In Bluespec System Verilog I would like to have a Vector of the same module but with different type parametrisations. I am trying to do something along the lines of this:
Module#(1) m1 <- mkModule;
Module#(2) m2 <- mkModule;
Module#(3) m3 <- mkModule;

Vector#(3, Module) v = cons(m1, cons(m2, cons(m3, nil)));

I have tried this
typedef union tagged {
    Module#(1) M1;
    Module#(2) M2; 
    Module#(3) M3;
} ModuleParametrisations deriving(Bits);

Module#(1) m1 <- mkModule;
Module#(2) m2 <- mkModule;
Module#(3) m3 <- mkModule;

Vector#(3, ModuleParametrisations) v = cons(M1(m1), cons(M2(m2), cons(M3(m3), nil)));

Which does compile but then there is awkwardness trying to call functions on these modules. I cannot just do v[0].func1() for example, type system doesn't like that. I would have to make a case statement it seems. This is a fairly straightforward thing that should probably be possible, and likely is but I am unsure how to get around the type system to do this sort of parametrisation
If this isn't possible in BSV is anything similar possible? I pretty much just want something that can be iterated over which holds different versions of the same module with different parametrisations

If it is possible to move the parameterization to the module rather than the interface, try:
typedef struct {} NumProxy #(numeric type n);
// or for general, non-numeric types:
// typedef struct {} Proxy #(type t);

interface Module;
// not parameterized with n anymore
// could still be parameterized with other things,
// but they must be given the same type to belong to the same Vector
endinterface
module mkModule#(NumProxy#(n) _unused) (Module);
  // ... use n as you would if it where a parameter of the Module interface
endmodule

NumProxy#(1) pxy1 = error("don't look inside a proxy");
NumProxy#(2) pxy2 = error("don't look inside a proxy");
NumProxy#(3) pxy3 = error("don't look inside a proxy");

Module m1 <- mkModule(pxy1);
Module m2 <- mkModule(pxy2);
Module m3 <- mkModule(pxy3);

Vector#(3, Module) v = cons(m1, cons(m2, cons(m3, nil)));


(plus or minus typos ;))
